# Building Kibana 5.2 visualization based on the data in the document (keys as X axis, values as Y) instead of aggregation

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-5

Here is a sample document in my index:

```
{"_id":"2018:05:03:19","_source":{"0":9926,"1":53436,"2":81151,"3":56466,"4":29904,...}}.
```

I am trying to build a bar chart where instead of using aggregation I need to take the keys (0, 1, 2, etc) to use as X axis and corresponding values as Y.  All aggregation has already been done in my pipeline.

Has anyone tried something like that?  I would really appreciate any suggestions as I am really stuck.

Thank you, 
Dmitry

Answer (score 0):

My data looks like the following format and works very well:

```
{ "_index": "my_index_name", "_type": "doc", "_id": "a_random_id", "_source": {"key1": 9926, "key2": 53416, ...}}
{ "_index": "my_index_name", "_type": "doc", "_id": "a_random_id", "_source": {"key1": 9926, "key2": 53416, ...}}
...
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for responding.  But how did you build the visualization?

Comment: I used simple Kibana bar chart, the tricky part is you use SUM, but when you select X axis it shows the actual key value, as the aggregation part is divided by key values.